# Crystal report-how to not sum suppressed field

Tags: crystal-reports, report, formula-editor

I got a invoice that need to suppress the data if the item-code is not match my suppress condition, then I have to do a running total on the line total!

I don't know what is the formula to sum only the field where suppressed is false.

My current formula is below, I wonder can I "If the LineTotal is not suppressed, then sum the linetotal else 0"

```
IF {OITM.ItmsGrpCod} = 112 then
   sum ({INV1.LineTotal})
else 0
```

[This my invoice, because this is the Haulage Copy, so we don't want show them the item price of each item.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFGAN.jpg)

Comment: what is your suppress condition?

Answer (score 0):

Best way to achive this requirement is to:

Create the running total for all `item - code' and write a supress condition for the section to supress the code which doesn't need to display.

`your idea of summing only if not supressed will complicate the report`, So try the way suggested